# 'IonicStorageModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

i want to do it like the offical documentation from ionic storage. but it says that "index.d.ts(9, 9): This likely means that the library (@ionic/storage-angular) which declares IonicStorageModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy."

how can i get rid of this error?

my code looks app.module.ts looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage-angular';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, IonicStorageModule.forRoot()],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in the current @ionic/storage-angular package

see https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage/issues/293 for more info.

Quick fix :

```
npm install @ionic/storage-angular@4.0.0-next.4
```